# Adding CORS Configuration with Spring + RSocket + Websocket

Tags: spring-security, rsocket, spring-rsocket

How do I add CORS configuration to restrict to a set of allowed hosts to make requests to a websocket exposed via RSocket?

I tried @CrossOrigin annotation without any luck and I have tried adding the below without any luck. All the samples I could find about RSocket does not cover CORS / SSL etc which are all required to build any serious application.

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
        corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(FRONTEND_LOCALHOST, FRONTEND_STAGING));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
                new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://allowed-origin.com"));
        corsConfig.setMaxAge(8000L);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("Baeldung-Allowed");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
                new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }
```